# kubernets monitoring system(prometheus+grafana+exporter) not using helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, grafana, exporter

I am trying to make monitoring system not using helm chart(Prometheus  and exporter and grafana)
cuz, it's offline environment.
but when I find there's only examples using Prometheus helm chart
are there any ways to use Prometheus, exporter without helm chart?
I expect any solution

Comment: actually you can but why the hard way? 
in order to achieve that you need to understand very well the architecture of the stack, I hope this article help: 
https://devopscube.com/setup-prometheus-monitoring-on-kubernetes/

Comment: so you mean that not using helm chart, the article you gave to me is the best way to build monitoring system?

Comment: no it just helps you understand the architecture of the stack in order to know how to build them in your environment, note that prometheus, node exporter and garfana are not the ultimate solution to define it as monitoring system as it only helps you monitor your infrastructure.

Comment: i found other ways to build monitoring system but the [prometheus, node exporter and garfana] is the best stack for me. so i just asked about how to install stacks using helm chart in offline environment or install not using helm chart

Comment: i got it, you should've mentioned it's okay to use helm but offline. anyways, in this case you first pull the chart using `helm pull <x / y>` then unzip it using `tar -xzvf <chart name>`, customize the values.yaml and templates, then install it using helm command `helm install <name> -n <name sapce> </path/to/chart>`

Comment: the only thing i have to do is change the image repository right? because it's offline

Comment: not just it but also configuration related to security, storage, rbac, dns if needed and so on